# Extract Album art image from HTML5 Audio after metadata loads using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please tell me how can I extract the album art image of an **mp3** song, linked with an HTML5 `<audio>` element, as soon as the metadata loads **without making another HTTP request**.

"I want something just like this":

```
$('audio').on('loadedmetadata', function(){
    // Extract AlbumArt
)};
```

I want the solution in jQuery/JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the 'song' contains embedded ID3 information you can use this library to read it out: https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader. If it does not have the embedded data, then you will not be able to do what you require.

Comment: That github page says to use this instead: https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

Comment: @Christian4423 good point - although the restrictions are the same